# Navigate to jsp2 from a form in jsp1

Tags: jsp, forms

This is my code in JSP1:

```
 <form action="./JSP2.jsp" name="DisplayDetails" method="GET">            
     <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
 </form>
```

Both the jsps reside in the same directory named (/WEB-INF).

Is this the right way to call one JSP from a `form` in another JSP?

Comment: if both jsps reside in the same WEB-INF folder,you can have the name of the target jsp in the **action** as **"action=JSP2"**.And the same thing applies on the target servlet too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a proper one but i guess JSP2.jsp is enough instead of ./JSP2.jsp